# Using Jquery and XMLHttpRequest to preselect options from multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, select, xmlhttprequest

I have a single select box that displays options. When a user selects an option I use XMLHttpRequest to fetch another selct box based on the value of the first select.
This works fine when a user is doing it to select options.
When the user now wants to edit this, Im using Jquery to preselect each item from the select boxes and automatically produce his previously chosen selections.
There are a maximum of 5 select boxes.
Im using setTimeout to run the next "select the value" function.

The script works fine in Chrome in my browser, but it doesnt work correctly in others.

here is my code:

```
function oc(a)
    {
      var o = {};
      for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
        o[a[i]]='';
      }
      return o;
    }

    var allcats =  new Array(<? echo substr($catarr, 0, -1); ?>);

    $("#catchoice1 option").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        if( name in oc(allcats) ) {
        var selectedcategory = name;    
        setTimeout(catpop1(selectedcategory),1000,true); /// getting a script error on this line in IE.
        setTimeout(catpop2,1000,true);
        $("#catschosen").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#catschosen").attr('checked', true);
        $("#Tags3").attr('disabled',false);         
        }
    });



function catpop1(name) { $("#catchoice1 option[value="+name+"]").attr('selected', 'selected').change(); }; 
function catpop2() { 
$("#catchoice2 option").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
        if( name in oc(allcats) ) {
        var selectedcategory = name; 
        $("#catchoice2 option[value="+name+"]").attr('selected', 'selected').change();      
        }
    }); 
    setTimeout(catpop3,1000,true);
    $("#catschosen").attr('checked', true);
    $("#Tags3").attr('disabled',false);         
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the function here: `setTimeout(catpop1(selectedcategory),1000,true);` to just `catpop1(selectedcategory);` without calling a function simplified the whole thing and removed the error.

this had nothing to do with the XMLHttpRequest either.. whats good to note is that that particular line was throwing an error - no wonder!